# Closures in Javascript - beginner question

Tags: javascript, closures

I read through countless articles when it comes to closures, yet I'm still struggling with it. Maybe someone could explain to me, why the function does not work as intended.

```js
let counter = (key) => {
  let counter = 10;
  if (key === 'milk') {
    ++counter;
  }
  if (key === 'bread') {
    --counter;
  }
  return function() {
    console.log(counter)
  }
}

let shopping = counter();
shopping('milk'); //  why not 11
shopping('milk'); //  12
shopping('bread'); //  11 
shopping('bread'); //  10
```

To me, it should always increment or decrement the counter depending on the parameter as the current state (counter) is saved in the shopping variable. However, the output right now is always 10.

Comment: Firstable the `key` parameter should belong to the returned function and not to the higher level function also the condition and incrementing and decrementing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
>  let shopping = counter();
> ```

You call `counter` and pass it no arguments. `key` is undefined. Neither of the `if` statements trigger.

> ```
>  shopping('milk');
> ```

You call `shopping` which is the function **returned** by `counter` that looks like this:

> ```
> function(){
>     console.log(counter)
> }
> ```

While you pass it an argument, it doesn't do *anything* with it. It just logs the current value of counter.

---

The only use for a closure in what you are trying to do is to protect the `counter` variable.

*Everything* else that function does is logic you need to run *every time* the returned function is called, so everything else should be in that returned function.

```js
let counter = () => {
  let counter = 10;

  return function(key) {
    if (key === 'milk') {
      ++counter;
    }
    if (key === 'bread') {
      --counter;
    }
    console.log(counter)
  }
}

let shopping = counter();
shopping('milk');
shopping('milk');
shopping('bread');
shopping('bread');
```

Answer (score 1):

From the way you call `shopping` you seem to want to pass it an argument and you want the counter variable to change by it.

The thing is, you have implemented this logic on the outer function instead of implementing it on the *returned* function.

So for it to work as you seem to wish, you need to move both the parameter and the logic inside the *returned* function:

```js
let counter = () => {
  let counter = 10;

  return function(key) {
    if (key === 'milk') {
      ++counter;
    }
    if (key === 'bread') {
      --counter;
    }
    console.log(counter);
  }
}

let shopping = counter();
shopping('milk');
shopping('milk');
shopping('bread');
shopping('bread');
```

Remark: you make things a bit more difficult to interpret, by giving two different variables the same name: `counter`. Readability will improve when you choose distinct names.

Answer (score 1):

Firstable the `key` parameter should belong to the returned function and not to the higher level function also the conditions of incrementing and decrementing

```js
let counter = () => {
    let counter = 10;
    return function(key) {
        if(key === 'milk') {
            ++counter;
        } else if(key === 'bread') {
            --counter;
        }
        console.log(counter);
    }
}

let shopping = counter();
shopping('milk');           //  11
shopping('milk');           //  12
shopping('bread');          //  11 
shopping('bread');          //  10
```